# How to select a range of cells from a datasheet and display in a drop-down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react and react-datasheet plugin.
I have a task where I am trying to select a range of cells from a datasheet and would like to display these selected cells attributes in a dropdown. I have no clue how I will be able to achieve this task.

Any help will appreciate it. If my explanation isn't clear, please comment I will explain more

[image: example image]

In the example above, the 3 heading cells should be selectable, giving a list of 3 attributes:


** Date

** Temperature Value

** Temperature UoM

Here is the plugin [link](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet)!

Here what I tried Until now

```
<ReactDataSheet
          style={{ overflow: "auto" }}
          className="tableScroll"
          data={rowData.cells}
          valueRenderer={cell => cell.value}
          onSelect={({ start, end }) => {

          console.log(start)
          console.log(end)

          // selectedAttributes data need to this formate: // [[0,start.i,start.j]];

          let spreadSheet_id = 0
          const selectedAttributes = spreadSheetData.sample_data[spreadSheet_id].cells.slice(start[0], start[1]).map(i => i.slice(end[0], end[1]));
          console.log(selectedAttributes)
          HttpService.putLegacyAttributes(spreadSheetData._id,selectedAttributes)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.sendStatusNotification("ERROR", err);
            });
           }}
         });
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?  It looks like the docs have some basic usage.  Is your data in the format it expects?

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks for your reply yes my data is in the formate is expected.
I need to select this cell gets the value from this cell and need to merge with others attribute, which will be in the different drop-down. 

I haven't tried anything as I don't have an idea of how I will approach this problem and achieve my goal as I am new in react will appreciate it if you could give some example thanks a million

Comment: @Mark Hi Marl that's I tried until now. I want to select from a spreadsheet and then want to display select cell in the drop-down.
I added my code

Comment: Please if anyone can give a little help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for this library and that I am very confused at what you are trying to achieve maybe something like this...

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      grid: [
        [{date:  1}, {temp_value:  3}], // Your grid values here
        [{date  2}, {temp_value:  4}],
        [{date:  5}, {temp_value:  6}],
        [{date:  7}, {temp_value:  8}],
        [{date:  9}, {temp_value:  10}],
        [{date:  11}, {temp_value:  12}],
      ],
      startingIndex: 0,
      endingIndex: 0
    }
  }

  // I don't know how your app is set up, but you will need to set the
  // starting and ending index somehow.  This is 'pseudocode'

  setRange = (start, end) => {
    this.setState({
      startingIndex: start,
      endingIndex: end
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { startingIndex, endingIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <ReactDataSheet
        data={this.state.grid}
        valueRenderer={(cell) => cell.value}
        onCellsChanged={changes => {
          const grid = this.state.grid.filter((row, idx) => {
            return idx >= startingIndex && idx <= endingIndex
          })
          changes.forEach(({cell, row, col, value}) => {
            grid[row][col] = {...grid[row][col], value}
          })
          this.setState({grid})
        }}
      />

      // Display the items in a select menu 
      // also pseudocode as I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve

      <select>
        { 
          this.state.grid.map(row => {
            const { date } = row[0];
            return <option value={date}>{date}</option>;
          })
        }
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```